# Mapping blue + orange key combination into another key in zebra android device (WT6300)

Tags: android

I want to remap blue + orange key combination into another key in zebra android devices.
**Example : blue + orange + 1** keys should be remapped into **_ (underscore)** mark. I used the stage now zebra application but it can not map blue + orange combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to remap a blue + orange key combination I'm afraid, to map it would need to be either blue + key or orange + key but it could not be blue + orange + key.  You could define both remappings (blue + key and orange + key) to achieve a similar behaviour to what you are looking for.

The documentation (https://techdocs.zebra.com/mx/keymappingmgr/) says: "If multiple Key State Modifiers are set in the Current Key State, the Key Mapping Tables associated with those Key State Modifiers are searched in a fixed priority order based on their associated Key State Modifiers. If a Key Mapping for the pressed Key is found at any time during a search, searching stops and the found Key Mapping will be used to determine the Key Behavior to be performed for the pressed Key."